# Your Sound Design Stack Exchange Moderation Team

Tags: discussion, moderation

There have been quite a few major changes in the recent months for the Social Sound Design and Audio production communities. One community was just absorbed into the larger Stack Exchange network after being on their own for a few years, the other was split from an established beta site.

We're now at the point where Sound Design Stack Exchange is the place that both communities call home, and we've got some fantastic people helping to steer things. While some of you might know everyone, I wanted to take a moment just to introduce your moderators, the leaders and constables of this new, much larger community.

First, the team that helped to make Social Sound Design the success that it is today:

[image: profile for Andrew Spitz at Sound Design Stack Exchange, Q&A for sound engineers, producers, editors, and enthusiasts]


[image: profile for Iain McGregor at Sound Design Stack Exchange, Q&A for sound engineers, producers, editors, and enthusiasts]


[image: profile for Jay Jennings at Sound Design Stack Exchange, Q&A for sound engineers, producers, editors, and enthusiasts]

And now, the team that led the thriving community at Audio & Video Production, many of which are now joining Sound Design:

[image: profile for Friend Of George at Sound Design Stack Exchange, Q&A for sound engineers, producers, editors, and enthusiasts]


[image: profile for JoshP at Sound Design Stack Exchange, Q&A for sound engineers, producers, editors, and enthusiasts]


[image: profile for Warrior Bob at Sound Design Stack Exchange, Q&A for sound engineers, producers, editors, and enthusiasts]

Finally, a new addition to the team:

[image: profile for Rory Alsop at Sound Design Stack Exchange, Q&A for sound engineers, producers, editors, and enthusiasts]

Rory is a long-term moderator on the Stack Exchange network, with quite a bit of experience on some of our established sites. He joined the team while helping with the large migration project, and will remain on with his usual light handed moderation approach.

These teams have come together to make sure that the needs and voices of all in this new, much larger community are heard and represented. These folks are here to help you continue to build this site into the best resource for sound on the Internet. You'll see them leaving guidance on some of your posts, answering support questions here on your meta site, and making sure that your larger concerns get in front of us, the Stack Exchange community team.

Be sure to say hello to them when you see them, and remember that they're completely volunteer - here to help you make the best site that you possibly can.